# Change the value of Associate to WebSite

Tags: adminhtml, customer, database

In the Backoffice of mine Application that uses Mangento, I have a list with all clients.

And in the Column “Site” I have 2 values, “Admin” and “Main Website”.

So, I wanted to know, when I try to edit some specific client, how can I change the “Associate to Website” value, because it is unclickable.

Thanks.
[image: customer grid]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20238909/901449

Answer (score 5):

The fields website and store view are disabled on purpose.  See this code in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account::initForm`.

```
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $form->getElement('website_id')->setDisabled('disabled');
        $form->getElement('created_in')->setDisabled('disabled');
    }
```

I don't know the exact reason but I can speculate and say this is because in Magento you have the possibility of splitting accounts by website.
So in theory 2 accounts can exist for the same customer but on 2 different websites from the same instance.
If you were allowed to change the website and store view you might have a duplicate account on the same website.
If your accounts are global or you have a single website (like you seam to have) then you can rewrite the method I mentioned above and remove the code that disables the fields. But I wouldn't recommend it. When there is a constraint, it is there for a good reason (most of the time).